# jsx react debugger not matching despite webpack source maps

Tags: debugging, google-chrome-devtools, reactjs, source-maps

I'm learning React and JSX and using webpack to compile but when I throw in 'debugger' into my component, the line isn't matched when I'm in Chrome Dev Tools' Sources tab (in general the sources doesn't reflect what I have in my app.jsx file at all). The React tab doesn't really load up either. Below is my webpack.config:

```
module.exports = {
  context: __dirname,
  entry: "./api_assignment.jsx",
  output: {
    path: "./",
    filename: "bundle.js"
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      {
        test: /\.jsx?$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        loader: 'babel',
        query: {
          presets: ['react']
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  devtool: 'source-map',
  resolve: {
    extensions: ["", ".js", ".jsx"]
  }
};
```

[image]

//Webpack screenshot

[image]

[image]

Comment: Please, could you post a screenshot within the folder webpack://?

Comment: @Shiroo just updated with screenshot

Comment: Did you try other webpack source map option ? https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#devtool . `eval` works for me

Answer (score 3):

If you are loading your html from local file and not webpack server, you need to enable React Developer Tools extension option "Allow access to file URLs".

Comment: I did that but I'm also using webpack server. React tab sometimes load up, but is there a way to make the sources tab's lines sync up with what I see in my jsx file?

Comment: Could you post screenshot?

Comment: sorry for late reply, I've posted the screenshot. As you can see chrome dev tools say my problem is on line 55, but there is no view variable there. the first my editor has the variable view is on line 112